reflexive relation trick question with statements
By my telegram group of teachers we got another challenging problem from High school stuff
If $R1$ and $R2$ are two reflexive relations on a non-empty set, then the incorrect statement is
(a): $R_1^{-1}$ U $R_2^{-1}$ is reflexive relation in the set
(b): $ R_1^{-1}\cap R_2^{-1}$ is reflexive relation in the set
(c): $R_1^{-1} \cap R_2^{1}$ reflexive relation in the set
(d): $R_1^{-1}-R_2^{-1}$ is reflexive relation in the set
my attempt: we know that (a,a) ordered pair are reflexive so inverse also will be same relation now option (a,b,c,d) as looks correct to me
But given answer is D

@xxxxxxxxx i am new at latex sorry let me fix it

@xxxxxxxxx check it now

Given the case $R_1,R_2$ reflexive,
The relations $R^{-1}_1$ , $R_1$, $R^{-1}_{2}$, $R_2$ are all Reflexive. So does the Intersection and Unions of any of these Relations.
For any sets $X,Y$ the set $X - Y$ contains all elements of X which are not found common in Y.
Hence The relation $R^{-1}_1 - R^{-1}_{2}$ cannot be reflexive since $(a,a) \in  R^{-1}_1 \cap R^{-1}_{2} \quad \forall \quad a$

X,Y are reflexive relation then when we X-Y we are left with all the elements which only persent in X so it is also reflexive

But the elements of the form (a,a) are also present in Y as well, and X - Y eliminates such elements...

But X is also reflexive so we are just removing common elements suppose we have x={(11),(22),(33)} and y={(11,22)} x-y will be ={33} which is also reflexive no?k

For example, A = {1,2,3) X ,Y are reflexive relations defined as
$X = {11,22,33,13,23}$ and $Y = {11,22,33,31}$ what is $X-Y$?

i got the mistake now. Thanks vishalnaakar sir

Why am I getting downvotes for this good question?
